# Can't log into instagram using instaloader: incorrect password

Tags: python, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instaloader

I'm trying to gather a list of my instagram followers using instaloader python module, but I get the error:

```
instaloader.exceptions.ConnectionException: Login error: "fail" status, message "Sorry, your password was incorrect. Please double-check your password.".
```

But I know my password is right. And I'm using VPN while running the script, can that be an issue? Because I'm running from the IP I've never logged into my account from.

Here's the code:

```
# Get instance
import instaloader

L = instaloader.Instaloader()

# Login or load session
username = "login"
password = "password"
L.login(username, password)  # (login)

# Obtain profile metadata
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, username)

print(profile.get_followers())
```

Also, I tried r'password', and it didn't work either. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the

```
password = "password"
```

to

```
password = r"password"
```

It may also be that Instagram just blocked your requests for few minutes - it should work if you would wait some time. You can also try logging in from the Instagram website, then try again.

Also, your password should not contain an ":".